# Consume php webservice in .net (VS2010)

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010

I have a webservice, written in PHP, which I want to consume in a .NET application. I have used the standard SoapServer implementation of PHP, with a selfwritten WSDL file. Here is the WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="Calculator"
             targetNamespace="urn:Calculator"
             xmlns:tns="urn:Calculator"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <!-- Definition of types used in the WSDL http://localhost/services/wsdl/CalculatorService.wsdl -->
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNameSpace="urn:Calculator">
            <xsd:element name="Reflect" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="ReflectResponse" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="GimmePiResponse" type="xsd:float" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>

    <!-- Abstract definition of the data being transmitted in -->
    <message name="CalculatorService_Reflect_InputMessage">
        <part name="stringToEcho" element="tns:Reflect" />
    </message>

    <!-- Abstract definition of the data being transmitted out -->
    <message name="CalculatorService_Reflect_OutputMessage">
        <part name="return" element="tns:ReflectResponse" />
    </message>

    <message name="CalculatorService_GimmePi_OutputMessage">
        <part name="return" element="tns:GimmePiResponse" />
    </message>

    <!-- A set of abstract operations referring to input and output messages -->
    <portType name="CalculatorServiceOperations">
        <operation name="Reflect">
            <input message="tns:CalculatorService_Reflect_InputMessage" />
            <output message="tns:CalculatorService_Reflect_OutputMessage" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="GimmePi">
            <output message="tns:CalculatorService_GimmePi_OutputMessage" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <!-- Concrete protocol and data format specifications -->
    <binding name="HttpBinding_CalculatorService" type="tns:CalculatorServiceOperations">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="Reflect">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ReflectAction"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Calculator" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Calculator" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GimmePi">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:GimmePiAction"/>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Calculator" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <!-- Specifies location and bindings for a service -->
    <service name="CalculatorService">
        <port name="CalculatorServiceOperations" binding="tns:HttpBinding_CalculatorService">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/services/CalculatorService.php" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Along with that I have the following webservice implementation:

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded("soap"))
{
    dl("php_soap.dll");
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer("CalculatorService.wsdl");

function GimmePi()
{
    return 3.14;
}

function Reflect($stringToEcho)
{
    return $stringToEcho;
}

$server->AddFunction("GimmePi");
$server->AddFunction("Reflect");

$server->handle();
?>
```

If I communicate with this service using SoapUI, it works like a charm, methods get called and return what they are supposed to.

Now I am trying to consume the same webservice in a .NET application, but for some reason, it does not generate the proxy class and I am not able to use it.

Does anyone has had this problem before or knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that WSDL looks to be `rpc/encoding` rather than `document/literal`. These don't behave as expected with the `DataContractSerialiser`.

you should try `svcutil` to generate the .cs from there. more options.

if you can host the `php` service online and point me to a `wsdl`, i'd be happy to try.

Comment: I've got the wsdl file online, but the service does not work yet; must have something todo with php settings. Check the following URL: http://services.jpbruins.nl/services/CalculatorService.wsdl

Comment: Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporterError: Schema with target namespace 'urn:Calculator' could not be found.XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:Calculator']/wsdl:portType[@name='CalculatorServiceOperations']

Comment: okay, first error is to the with the targetNamespace urn:Calculator in <definition/> should this not be a path?

Comment: <definitions name="Calculator" targetNamespace="http://services.jpbruins.nl/services/CalculatorService.wsdl"> like that?

Comment: according to all the examples... no. But I found out a much more disturbing fact. My provider does not have the SOAP extension enabled for PHP! This makes my whole research void. I'll probably end up going to a provider which supports .net ,then I can do WCF... Thanks foir your support though

Comment: yup, that is a deal breaker! After looking over the `wsdl`, it is definately a `rpc/encoding` problem.